# Deleting a mutex that is locked

Tags: c++, mutex

I have a program with multiple resources that needs to be lock by their own mutex.

In this program, it might happen that while mutex for *resource A* is locked, *resource A* is deleted in another thread.

The following code try to reproduce the logic of what I try to accomplish :

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
int g_i = 0;
struct Resource
{
    std::mutex* m_mutex;
};

std::map<unsigned int, Resource> myResources;

std::mutex g_i_mutex;  // protects g_i

void shutdown()
{
    std::cout << "shutdown -> myMap.size = : " << myResources.size() << std::endl;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*myResources[1].m_mutex);
    ++g_i;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    delete myResources[1].m_mutex;
    myResources[1].m_mutex = NULL;
    myResources.erase(1);
    std::cout << "shutdown -> myMap.size = : " << myResources.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shutdown : " << g_i << '\n';


}

 void onRecognize()
{
    std::cout << "onRecognize -> myMap.size = : " << myResources.size() << std::endl;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*myResources[1].m_mutex);
    std::cout << "onRecognize -> myMap.size = : " << myResources.size() << std::endl;
    ++g_i;

    std::cout <<  "onRecognize : " << g_i << '\n';


}

int main()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << ": " << g_i << '\n';
    Resource myStruct;
    myStruct.m_mutex = new std::mutex();
    myResources[1] = myStruct;
    std::thread t1(shutdown);
    std::thread t2(onRecognize);

    t1.join();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    t2.join();

    std::cout << __func__ << ": " << g_i << '\n';
}
```

I tried this snippet of code and it works.  But I am wondering what happen with *lock_guard* in *onRecognize* function, because the mutex is being deleted while he is locked.  So, my question might be :

Does deleting a mutex while he is locked somewhere else is dangerous?

Thx

Comment: "In this program, it might happen that while mutex for resource A is locked, resource A is deleted in another thread." - then that's already a concurrency bug, regardless of what happens to the mutex. Whoever's holding that lock expects to be able to use resource A without other threads screwing with it.

Comment: I believe it is undefined behavior

Comment: Any thread that wants to touch resource A for any reason needs to obtain the mutex lock first. That way, it would not be possible to one thread to delete the resource while another thread holds the lock.  In this code, `shutdown()` is obtaining the mutex lock before deleting the mutex, but it is deleting the mutex while it is still locked. It needs to unlock the mutex before deleting the mutex, but that is still a race condition on the mutex itself, because as soon as it is unlocked, another thread can lock it before it gets deleted. Don't delete a mutex while other thread can still use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't destroy a mutex while it is locked.

> The behavior is undefined if the mutex is owned by any thread or if any thread terminates while holding any ownership of the mutex.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/~mutex

Answer (score 3):

You have a fundamental concurrency error that renders your code unreliable.     The pointer `m_mutex` is modified in one thread and used in another, and no synchronization of any kind protects it.

This is catastrophic even if you can't imagine a way it can fail. But it happens to be very easy to imagine ways it can fail. Consider:

1. `onRecognize` evaluates `*myResources[1].m_mutex` but hasn't constructed the lock guard yet.
2. `shutdown` acquires the lock, destroys the mutex, and returns.
3. `onRecognize` tries to construct the lock guard on a lock that no longer exists.
4. Boom.

So you have bigger problems than anything specific to the semantics of mutexes.

Answer (score 0):

GCC(10.2) & Clang(10) don't have issues with deleting a locked mutex, MSVC 19.28 will terminate.

```
{
    std::mutex m;
    m.lock();
}//std::terminate() - MSVC
```

Comment: The C++ spec states that "The behavior is undefined if the mutex is owned by any thread or if any thread terminates while holding any ownership of the mutex."