# How to thread-safely delete resources with my mutex

Tags: c++, mutex

I try to find a way to safely delete me resources and my mutex, without race conditions indeed.  Could someone tell me if this code looks alright?

```
struct Resource
{
    std::string m_resource;
};
struct Mutex
{
    std::mutex* m_mutex;
};

std::map<unsigned int, Resource> myResources;
std::map<unsigned int, std::mutex*> myMutexes;


void shutdown(int UUID)
{
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(*myMutexes[UUID]);
        myResources.erase(UUID);
    }
    // No need anymore this mutex, because associated resource is deleted
    delete myMutexes[UUID];
    myMutexes.erase(UUID);    
}

void onRecognize(int UUID)
{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(*myMutexes[UUID]);
    if (myResources.find(UUID) != myResources.end() )
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

int main()
{
    myResources[1] = "resA";
    myMutexes[1] = new std::mutex();
    std::thread t1(shutdown);
    std::thread t2(onRecognize);

    t1.join();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    t2.join();

}
```

So, is it safe how I deal with my mutex in *shutdown* function?  Or there is still chances that my mutex  being deleted just right before reaching *lock_guard* in *onRecognize* function?

My final goal is I want to lock only for one resource.

So, in the following calls

```
shutdown(2);
onRecognize(1);
```

*onRecognize* does not need to wait after *shutdown*, because he does not work on same resource.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to define a class encapsulating the resource and the mutex, rather than parallel maps?

Comment: @AlanStokes I tried a solution encapsulating my ressource and his mutex in a struct.  But it causes other problems see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030156/deleting-a-mutex-that-is-locked/34030354#34030354

Comment: For a shutdown() method, can you just call shutdown() from main(), only after all of your spawned threads have been join()'d?  That way there is no possibility of a race condition, since your main() thread will be the only thread still running.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The example above is really simplistic and does not reflect totally what I try to do in my code.  I am running a server and the server manages clients calls.  He is always up and running.  At some point, client close the connection and server needs to clean resources associated with the client.

Comment: In that case, my suggestion would be to manage your dynamically-allocated objects using shared_ptr's rather than raw pointers.  That way you don't need to manually delete the resources; instead the last thread that holds a shared_ptr pointer pointing to a resource will delete it (inside the shared_ptr's destructor).  shared_ptrs use thread-safe reference counting so they should "just work" for this purpose.